# ms-access: breaking up front and back end

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have an access database on a server. it is split up into front end and back end.

people are accessing the database's front end using a shortcut from their desktop computers.

i know for a fact that multiple people are using it at the same time.

for some reason, when i created a shortcut on my computer to access the front end of this database, i can open the file no problem, but if i try to view any tables or forms i am getting:

```
could not use .....file; file already in use
```

what does this mean?

Comment: Do you *ever* ask a question that is not at novice-level? Maybe you should post more of your questions on SuperUser.com, which seems to me to be more appropriate to the general level of problems you seem to encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what your error message means specifically.  I don't understand why Access would open the database file without complaint, but then spit an error when you attempt to view forms or tables.  I've never encountered that situation.

However, in a general sense, I think it means you should give each user their own copy of the FE database file ... instead of allowing everyone to directly open the same FE file on a network share.

Use Tony Toews' free [Auto FE Updater](http://autofeupdater.com/) to manage the distribution of the FE files to your users.  Then you can replace the existing desktop shortcuts with a shortcut to Tony's utility.  It's a slick way to ensure all the user's have the latest version of your FE, and by giving them their own copy avoids the problems inherent in allowing everyone to directly open the very same FE database file.

Also, read this page from Tony for more detailed information: [Splitting your Microsoft Access MDB into a front end and back end - Why?](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/splitapp/why.htm)

**Edit**: Perhaps the error message is because a user has the BE database opened exclusively.  They wouldn't need to open it in that mode, but when modifying a back end object, like a table design, Access will switch them to exclusive mode.  However, if this were the explanation, it seems like everyone except the exclusive user would be getting the same error message as you.  Are they?

Comment: hansup thanks very much this is super helpful. i am just waiting for dave's response,