# Make the front-end part of an access database read-only

Tags: ms-access

I have created an Access dababase that is split into a front end and a back end. The front end consists of a form and some VBA that communicates with the back end part in the separate file. Both these files live on a network share and users are opening the front end to communicate with the back end. (Can be multiple at the same time.)

Now I understood that a split database allows multiple users communicating with it simultaneously. And the back end file seems to hold up quite good. I have however faced that the front end part broke twice now because it got 'in an inconsistent state' (even though it contains not a single table).

I have already exported the front end as accde file assuming it would become some sort of executable, but the file's last changed information is updated with new times and users. As a last resort I have set the read-only flag on the file. This stopped the file from breaking, but now I get a lot of questions from uses telling me that the database has become read-only.

[image: read only warning]

Access is referring to the front end as the database, whereas the back end is still writable and the form works as it should.

I have read in [Deploying access database to program files without Read only warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053190/deploying-access-database-to-program-files-without-read-only-warnings) that access needs write access to the front-end to update the state of UI objects? Is that true? Will this set up eventually fail as well?

[ms-access: breaking up front and back end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320049/ms-access-breaking-up-front-and-back-end) also mentions that users should have their own versions of the front end. There is however a large number of changing users, so I really prefer the network share approach.

The ideal solution would be to create a small application that cannot be changed, and users are not faced with these unneeded warnings. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sadly, that warning message is unavoidable.

What you can do, is to launch the application from a shortcut that runs a script which, as the first step, overwrites a present local frontend with a fresh copy, thus overwriting any change the user might have made. Next, runs the frontend is as a *runtime*.

A method using a VBScript file is described in my article:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)

Comment: Hmm, missed opportunity for Microsoft there... Having the option to create an immutable front end seems to make a lot of sense. I'll see what possibilities I have for local deployment. Could be your VBA, but IMO a batch file with a few lines should do as well.

Comment: I gave up on a batch file and would have preferred PowerShell. But I had nearly all the building blocks as VBScript.